# How to find the value in cell range from cell value then find next

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA excel and I want to have a search system that is when im going to type the value in a particular cell then will search that value in a cell range. the macro must go to the first cell then select the next then next until no match is found. I have a code that i searched through the net but im having a hard time to figure this out.

Thank you for your help! :)

```
Sub FindADrug()

Dim DrugCell As Range
Dim SearchRange As Range
Dim SearchCell As String
Dim FirstDrugCell As String

SearchCell = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D6").Value

Set SearchRange = Range("A1:A335")

Set DrugCell = SearchRange.Find(What:=SearchCell, MatchCase:=False, LookAt:=xlPart)

If Not DrugCell Is Nothing Then
    DrugeCell.Select

Else
    FirstDrugCell = DrugCell.Address

    Do

        Set DrugCell = SearchRange.FindNext(DrugCell)


    Loop While DrugCell.Address <> FirstDrugCell

 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `DrugeCell.Select` should be `DrugCell.Select` but apart from that, I don't think the code is going to do what I think you want it to do because if there are more than 2 matches it'll set one as FirstDrugCell and then keep finding the other one. You should probably add the cells to an array and then test against that.

Comment: @Michael Bryan do you want it to loop to all cells where it finds matches on a single call to this code, or it should go one by one (every time you call this `Sub` it will select the next cell) ?

Comment: Hi Tim! I've changed the DrugeCell to DrugCell. Yes that's what i want the code to do. how do i add cells to an array? Thanks

Comment: @Shai Rado I just want the code to select one by one until no match is found..

Comment: @MichaelBryan when your `DrugCell Is Nothing`, it will go to the `Else` section, step inside the line `FirstDrugCell = DrugCell.Address` (which is Nothing) and you get an error !

Comment: Hi Shai, I've used your code but still doesnt select the next cell with the cell value, HCTZ. say i have list of drugs like Gabapentin
HCTZ
Ibuprofen
Lexapro
Lisinopril HCTZ
Loratadine
when i run the code, it goes to HCTZ but when i run the macro again, it doesnt go down to Lisinopril HCTZ..

Answer (score 0):

Please, can you try the following?

I have made small changes to your code.

First I have defined a name "`Drug`" which refers to Cell `D6` on `Sheet 1`. In this way if you decide to move your search cell you do not have to update the VBA code.

Second it is now using a cell, which you have to set as the defined name "`placeholder`" to store the row number of the last entry found. In this way the next time you run it it will go to the next entry (if any). When it gets to the last match if you run it again it will display a message box telling that there are no other matches. At the same time the value of "`placeholder`" is reset to `1` so you can start your search again.
That value is reset to one also when you change the value of cell `D6` (see `Worksheet_Change` subroutine).

```
Sub FindADrug()

  Dim DrugCell As Range
  Dim SearchRange As Range
  Dim SearchCell As String
  Dim FirstDrugCell As String
  Dim Counter As Integer

  Counter = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
  SearchCell = Range("Drug").Value

  Set SearchRange = Range("A1:A" & Counter)

  'Range("placeholder") refers to a defined name which is used to store the row of the last drug found.
  'You have to set it before using the macro.
  Set DrugCell = SearchRange.Find(What:=SearchCell, After:=Cells(Range("placeholder"), 1), MatchCase:=False, SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookAt:=xlPart)

  If DrugCell Is Nothing Then

     MsgBox "No drug found.", vbOKOnly, "No results..."

  Else

    FirstDrugCell = DrugCell.Address

    If DrugCell.Row < Range("placeholder").Value Then

      MsgBox "Last drug found", vbOKOnly, "Last drug"
      Range("placeholder") = 1

    Else

      Range("placeholder") = DrugCell.Row
      DrugCell.Select
      Set DrugCell = SearchRange.FindNext(DrugCell)

    End If

  End If

End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Row = 6 And Target.Column = 4 Then Range("placeholder") = 1
End Sub
```

I hope I have understood the issue correctly. Please, can you tell me if this solves the problem you have?